# How to optimize a php page to include users profile page in search results?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have no idea on how to optimize my profile.php page to include it in search results. i also tried to include meta description but nothing is happening.

I have asked the same question somewhere else, but they said it must be because of your .htaccess file.

here is my .htaccess file :

```
Options +Indexes
# or #
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What you mean by optimize? is it related with SEO?

Comment: kind of but by 'optimize' i mean what should i take care of each profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your rules aren't correct.

1. In general you should have 301 rules before internal rewrites.
2. You don't need a separate rule for trailing slash only.
3. Your 2 rewrite conditions won't apply for 2nd rewrite rule.

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i have one question , should i include sitemap or not as it is a social networking site.

Comment: I didn't see any sitemap specific rule in your .htaccess

Comment: it is related to seo that's why i am asking as there will be many profile page url's in it so is it good to include it.

Comment: Ok in that case you can include any sitemap specific rule but do test it out.